# Какие есть практики по оформлению сообщений логов?

Tags: code-style

Всё чаще на code-review замечаю, что мне не нравятся логи других программистов, а им не нравятся мои.

Обычно все правки аргументируются ссылками на code-style, но большинство (или все) из них обходят стороной тему форматирования сообщений и логгирование вообще. Выходит спор о вкусах, что не продуктивно.

Подскажите литературу или open-source проекты, где можно постичь дзен написания красивых и информативных логов, чтобы оформить свой log-style?

Comment: in4b: по запросу "logs style" в гугле найдёте треды про то, как сделать зеленый текст в консоли, а "code-style logs" выдаст инфу про уровни логгирования. Ссылки из вопроса https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926017/log-message-style-guide за 9 лет успели побиться